# How to write from one database to another using SPRING-Batch w/out translating the resultset into a list of temporary objects or a map?

Tags: java, spring-batch

Steps:

1. Read "Select x, y, z from TABLE_1" from Database1 into a ResultSet.
2. pass ResultSet to a Writer
3. Write all records returned by the ResultSet to TABLE_2 in Database2.

Requirement:

1. Do not create any unused Objects to hold the data after reading from the ResultSet. (i.e. no Table1.class)
2. Use as much pre-built functionality as possible from the SPRING-Batch framework.
3. No DB Link.

NOTE: Class names for me to reference are enough to get me on the right path.

Comment: I have a similar requirement with some additional checks before doing the insert. Did you get a stable solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

assuming you use [JdbcPagingItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html) and [JdbcBatchItemWriter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html) you can use:

- the [ColumnRowMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ColumnMapRowMapper.html) from spring-jdbc
- an self implemented [ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider.html)

Comment: Assuming i'm using spring batch/integration - would you have a recommendation on how i might Transform data between the Reader and the Writer steps in the simple job described above?

Answer (score 0):

Your wish to save on memory allocations are clear but think twice if your desire for maximum optimization is worse side effects and problems.

First of all, if you just want to read rows from table A and write them to table B without any transformation of the data, then Spring Batch is not the best choice. You wish to use Spring Batch in this scenario perhaps if you want to retry (using `RetryTemplate`) in case some exception occurred during writing, or you want to skip certain exceptions (e.g. `DataIntegrityViolationException` = ignore duplicate entries).

So what you can do (but that is not very good approach) is to use [Flyweight objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), e.g. the object that you return to framework is always the same, however it is each time filled with new contents (the code is not tested, AS IS):

```
package org.epo.lifesciences.chepo.service;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemStreamItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils;

public class FlyweightItemReader extends AbstractItemStreamItemReader<Object[]> {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource  dataSource;

    /*
     * State objects
     */
    private Connection  con;

    private Statement   stmt;

    private ResultSet   rs;

    private Object[]    row;

    /**
     * @see org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamSupport#open(org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext)
     */
    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        row = null;
        con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);

        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("some sql");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, dataSource);

            throw new ItemStreamException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamSupport#close()
     */
    @Override
    public void close() {
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, dataSource);

        JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(stmt);
        JdbcUtils.closeConnection(con);
    }

    /**
     * @see org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader#read()
     */
    public Object[] read() throws SQLException {
        if (!rs.next()) {
            // End of result set is reached:
            return null;
        }

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        if (row == null && columnCount > 0) {
            // Create the flyweight:
            row = new Object[columnCount];
        }

        // Copy all column values to flyweight:
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            row[i - 1] = JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(rs, i);
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

Be aware about this approach: it works only if your batch size is 1 (otherwise you end up with N equal objects in a batch) and only if your reader has prototype scope (because it is stateful).

Comment: will the data integrity remain intact while we are using the 'row' object while inserting in the target DB.

Comment: As I said, copying data from database to another one is not a suitable application of Spring Batch. In case if batch size is 1, then whole pipeline should work fine.