# A simple way to use Spring Batch for SQL-to-SQL processing?

Tags: sql, spring, spring-batch

You might think it's a silly question...

My need is very simple :
i would like to use (and push use of) Spring Batch in a very simple usecase.
A process which read in database, and write in database, without any kind of  transformation at first.
So it is a simple SQL-to-SQL process.

Is there any reader/writer object in Spring Batch which allow this ?
I mean : without any underlying O/R mapping (JDBC<==>objects).

JdbcCursorItemReader object needs a RowMapper.
But i don't need this. I don't need O/R overhead.

Thx in advance for your suggestions
Regards

Comment: I don't see how spring batch could support this ... without an underlying mapping to some type of Object. You could pass the raw result set to the writer so maybe you could skip the O/R mapping but it would still mean mapping from the result set in your JDBC writter.  edit: just noticed this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144052/how-to-write-from-one-database-to-another-using-spring-batch-w-out-translating-t